# setting html button to post back with confirm

Tags: jquery, .net

Hi I have a html button like so

```
<button type="button" runat="server" id="btnDelete" type="button" data-confirm-message="Deleting this page will permanently delete it from the system and it will not be recoverable. Are you sure you wish to continue?">delete</button>
```

Which generates this html

```
<button onclick="if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate(''); __doPostBack('ctl00$body$btnDelete','')" id="btnDelete" type="button"   data-confirm-message="Deleting this page will permanently delete it from the system and it will not be recoverable. Are you sure you wish to continue?">delete</button>
```

and some jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
        return confirm($(this).data("confirm-message"));
    });

});
```

The issue is the page is posted back regardless of the confirm being true or false, any help woudl eb great

Comment: That's because the inline JS fires before the event handler, and what is returned from the event handler has nothing to do with the inline onclick. Also, if one button generates the other button, you'd have two buttons with the same ID.

Comment: by generates the html I meant the html that is rendered by .net, but thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i removed the click event and re-attached after confirm is true

```
 $(".document-confirm-delete").each(function (index, item) {
        var clickEvents = this.onclick;
        this.onclick = null;
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            if (Document.ConfirmDelete(this)) {
                clickEvents();
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze your inline handler, you'll see that postback is performed every time the button is clicked trough `__doPostBack('ctl00$body$btnDelete','')`

```
if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') 
    Page_ClientValidate(''); 

__doPostBack('ctl00$body$btnDelete','') // this line is always reached on click
```

It doesn't matter if you return `false` from your jQuery click handler as inline code is executed anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to override this?

Comment: You could replace your `<button>` by a `<asp:button>` and use `OnClientClick` to place `return confirm($(this).data("confirm-message"));`

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you have an inline click handler with the `onclick` attribute which submits the form and will beat your jQuery click handler to it every time.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnDelete").removeAttr("onclick").click(function () {
        return confirm($(this).data("confirm-message"));
    });

});
```

It removes the `onclick` attribute so it can handle the click itself.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't submit at all. In debug Page_ClientValidate is not available

Comment: @DavidB Seems like the `Page_ClientValidate` function doesn't exist --- do you know what it should be doing? Just wondering if it's something deliberate on your part or whether it's some JS .NET has spat out automatically, as it often does.

Comment: its been spat out by .net, thin k the issue is the way it postbacks from a <button> click

Comment: @DavidB Okay, I just edited the answer to remove the `Page_ClientValidate` bit, let's see if it works now (and whether any other behaviour on the page changes).

Answer (score -1):

I see you're using .NET. One way you can prevent the postback is by wiring up OnClientClick for an ASP Button/LinkButton/etc.

```
OnClientClick="return confirm('Your Message');"
```

A response of `false` will prevent a postback, and then you can include your postback code in the `OnClick` handler for `true` responses. Would something like that work?

Comment: Explain the down-vote please. What I stated is 100% accurate.